# Fragment caching in yii: where should I load my model?

Tags: php, caching, yii

In general the good practice is to call the model only from the controller and then pass it to the view. Here's an example:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $this->loadModel((int)$id),
        ));
}
```

Then you can use `model` in the view to display the information.

The problem is that I want to implement fragment caching in my view:

```
<?php if($this->beginCache($id, array('duration'=>3600))) { ?>
...content to be cached...
<?php $this->endCache(); } ?>
```

But since the model has been loaded from the controller the sql query will be executed anyway. How can I prevent this from happening?

The only alternative that I'm finding right now is to load the model from the view (in the cached section) or to perform data caching, but I would prefer to use fragment caching!

Comment: There are different opinions about your proposition, that you should not access the model from views. While this is definitely true for *writing* something, *read access* to models can be perfectly fine in views. So i'd not follow MVC "good practices" blindly, if there's good reason, not to do so. In this case for example, I'd personally make an exception.

Comment: Thanks! Another solution would have been to create a new method in the controller calling the model and call this new method from the view. But at the end it's like calling the model from the view!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move caching to controller and use [data cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data) instead of fragment cache, ie:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = Yii::app()->cache->get((int)$id);
    if($model === false)
    {
        $model = $this->loadModel((int)$id);
        Yii::app()->cache->set($id, $model, 3600);
    }
    $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
}
```

You can still use fragment cache if needed (when you do something intensive with already loaded model), just prefix id with something.

Comment: That's right, but probably in your `loadModel` you have some loading logic too, like 404 exception when not found, so you will not get `null` instead of model instance. But, you could also make `loadModel` public, and access it from view like that: `$model = $this->loadModel();`